# How to test if an R object is a named numeric vector?

Tags: r, validation

I'd like to know if there is a simple and robust way to test if an object is a named `numeric` vector. Here is an example:

```
data <- c(2.3, 3.5, 5.7)
typeof(data)
#[1] "double"
mode(data)
#[1] "numeric"
str(data)
# num [1:3] 2.3 3.5 5.7
is.vector(data)
#[1] TRUE
is.numeric(data)
#[1] TRUE
```

So as you can see from the above, I have created a `numeric` `vector`. Now I assign names to the elements.

```
named_vec <- structure(data, names = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
named_vec <- structure(data, names = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
str(named_vec)
# Named num [1:3] 2.3 3.5 5.7
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
names(named_vec)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

I could use a few compound conditions such as:

```
if(is.vector(named_vec) & is.numeric(named_vec) & !is.null(names(named_vec)))           {
   "named_vec is a named numeric vector"
 } else {
   "named_vec is not a named numeric vector"
 }
#[1] "named_vec is a named numeric vector"
```

Or something like this, but it feels like it could fall prey to corner cases:

```
length(names(named_vec)) == length(named_vec)
#[1] TRUE
names(data)
#NULL
```

I'm looking for something that is concise and robust.

Comment: If you want a `vector` which is `numeric` and has `names`, then there is nothing wrong in testing each of the above separately. Your first solution looks fine to me.

Comment: Just create a function with your solution and give it a nice concise name, something like `is.named.numeric = function(x) ...`

Comment: `length(names(named_vec)[(names(named_vec) != "")]) == length(named_vec)` for named vectors with missing names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see in your firt solution (the if clause) is that the names of the vector could be incomplete, and I do not know if thats acceptable in your case.

In the second solution, a non-numeric named vector would pass the verification, right? And it seems to me that this is not what you desire.

If you could provide more details about what you want exactly to do with this verification, I could help you a little more.

It is also easier to do

```
is.vector(f, mode = "numeric")
```

Thus you verifie both conditions (vector and numeric). Read is.vector help.

Comment: @ursus, I am still not able to post comments in other answers than mine. But I think you got it. Justo to be more clear and concise if you write you write your function like this:  `IsNamedVector <- function(VECTOR) is.vector(VECTOR, mode = "numeric") &  !any(is.na(names(VECTOR)))`. With less tests and an inline function you are gonna have the same results!

Answer (score 2):

My answer simply combines the comments of @nicola and @Gregor along with the answer provided by @droubi:

Create a new function `IsNamedVector`. Below is example:

## Create Example Data Set

```
> data <- c(2.3, 3.5, 5.7)
> typeof(data)
[1] "double"
> mode(data)
[1] "numeric"
> str(data)
 num [1:3] 2.3 3.5 5.7
> is.numeric(data)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(data)
[1] TRUE
> named_vec <- structure(data, names = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
> str(named_vec)
 Named num [1:3] 2.3 3.5 5.7
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
> names(named_vec)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

## Create Custom Function

```
> IsNamedVector <- function(VECTOR) {
+   is.vector(VECTOR) & is.numeric(VECTOR) & !is.null(names(VECTOR)) & 
+      !any(is.na(names(VECTOR)))
+ }
```

## Test Function

```
> length(names(named_vec)) == length(named_vec)
[1] TRUE
> names(data)
NULL
> !all(is.na(names(named_vec)))
[1] TRUE
> missing_names_vec <- structure(data, names = c('a', 'b'))
> str(missing_names_vec)
 Named num [1:3] 2.3 3.5 5.7
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" NA
> IsNamedVector(named_vec)
[1] TRUE
> IsNamedVector(missing_names_vec)
[1] FALSE
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of tests, I use package [**checkmate**](http://mllg.github.io/checkmate/). It is fast and easy to use.

For named numeric vectors, check functions `test_numeric()`, `check_numeric()`, and `assert_numeric()` with parameter `names = "named"` (for other options, see [type](http://mllg.github.io/checkmate/reference/checkNamed.html#arguments) under "Arguments" section). The functions differ in output so you should decide, which is the most suitable for you.

Returns logical:

```r
checkmate::test_numeric(1, names = "named")
#> [1] FALSE
checkmate::test_numeric(c(a = 1), names = "named")
#> [1] TRUE
checkmate::test_numeric(c(a = "A"), names = "named")
#> [1] FALSE
```

Returns string:

```r
checkmate::check_numeric("1", names = "named")
#> [1] "Must be of type 'numeric', not 'character'"
checkmate::check_numeric(1, names = "named")
#> [1] "Vector must be named"
```

Returns error message:

```r
checkmate::assert_numeric(1, names = "named")
#> Error in withCallingHandlers({: Assertion on '1' failed: Vector must be named.
```